# If a character drops a magic item that turns on/off, does that item turn off when they drop it?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

If a character drops a magic item that turns on/off, does that item turn off when they drop it?

For instance, let's assume a character has a *sun blade*, and it is turned on. If they somehow lose that item in a fight, does it turn off the instant it leaves their hand? Does it turn off at all?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 22):

### An item's description will tell you the conditions for "turning it off/on".

In the case of a *Sun Blade*, a bonus action is required to make the blade (dis)appear and dropping it has no direct effect because it's not stated in the description:

> While grasping the hilt, you can use a bonus action to [...] make the blade disappear.

However, in the case of a *Flame Tongue* sword, dropping it *would* turn the flames off:

> The flames last [...] until you drop or sheathe the sword.